# How do i format the legend from a chart generated using Plotly to be uniform to any type of chart?

Tags: python, charts, plotly

I'm currently trying to create a chart using the following code

```
economiaAcumulada = [300, 700, 1200]
economiaMensal = [300, 400, 800]

meses = ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar']

OUTPUT_FORMAT = "png"

import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.subplots as sp
import plotly.express as px

def CriarGraficoAnaliseEconomica(acumulada, mensal, labels):
    fig = px.line(x=labels, y=acumulada, color=px.Constant("Economia Acumulada"),
             labels=dict(x="Meses", y="Valor", color=""))
    fig.add_bar(x=labels, y=mensal, name="Economia Mensal")
    fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
        yanchor="top",
        y=0.99,
        xanchor="left",
        x=0.01,
        
    ))
```

Which results in this
[image: Result]

Is there a way to format/change the legend from a Line chart to be a square like the Bar chart?

- I've tried switching the symbol property to 'square', but it didn't work for me.
- I've also tried creating a third chart(Bar chart) without values, and using the ShowLegend=True property to display the desired legend format but the selection by clicking, selects a hidden chart.